# How to make BREW sdk apps on a mac

Tags: macos, brew-framework, brewmp

I have an  [LG Cosmos Touch](http://www8.pcmag.com/media/images/283992-lg-cosmos-touch-verizon-wireless.jpg?thumb=y) and wanted to know if there was any way that I could make apps for it. I know it is possible on a windows computer but I have a mac. So, can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work, since we made it work on Linux, but it's not really easy and we had to do a lot of workarounds and in the end I used XP in a virtual machine.

Comment: I don't quite remember and also a colleague did most of the work. At least it's a testimony that it's not impossible. :-/  Possibly the signing software needs to run in Windows anyway too. Also, you need an unlock key from Qualcomm to actually load your app onto your phone.